# IOS Segue between Google Maps infoWindow and VC

Tags: google-maps, push, infowindow

I am trying to push to another vc from Google Maps infoWindow. So I connect segue from the vc hosting Google maps to the other vc.
When I called

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoView2Store" sender:self],
```

I received the following exception message:

```
Receiver (<MapView: 0x7fde105f3ac0>) has no segue with identifier 'infoView2Store'
```

I set Segue identifier correctly. What may I miss?

Comment: OMG! I got stuck in this for a week, and now not only could I get help, but I got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost a week to solve this, but could not find the way out. Finally, I change from Storyboard to IB. Now going to the new VC is fine by calling:

```
StoreViewController *controller = [[StoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StoreView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I am still interested to know if someone could push from infoWindow to a new VC thru Segue.